# Transition not triggering when hovered over

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I try to make a cube transition inside of a container when the trigger div is hovered over but it isn't triggering the transition. However, if I swap out the id of the trigger with something that isn't a class or id lets say body it works! The moment I switch it out for something that has a class or id again it stops working!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEwoXb

```css
pre {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.trans-box-holder {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px cornflowerblue solid;
}

.trans-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#trans_box_1 {
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}


/* If you swap out #pre_opacity for body it works for some reason! */

#pre_opacity:hover #trans_box_1 {
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<pre id="pre_opacity">
        .element {
            transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 1s;
        }
    </pre>
<div class="trans-box-holder">
  <div class="trans-box" id="trans_box_1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target it using `~`

```css
pre {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.trans-box-holder {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px cornflowerblue solid;
}

.trans-box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#trans_box_1 {
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
/* If you swap out #pre_opacity for body it works for some reason! */
#pre_opacity:hover ~ .trans-box-holder #trans_box_1 {
    transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}

#pre_opacity:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="example"></p>

<!-- The trigger -->
<pre id="pre_opacity">
    .element {
        transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 1s;
    }
</pre>
            <div class="trans-box-holder">
                <div class="trans-box" id="trans_box_1"></div>
            </div>
```

> The #trans_box_1 is a sibling of the container. Using `~` targets anything after the parent target which in this case could be `pre` or `#pre_opacity` or `pre#pre_opacity`

I also put an `example` tag as `<p class="example"></p>` just to explain better, you can also target the hover effect then like this `.example:hover ~ .trans-box-holder #trans_box_1` as the target is still after the parent `<p>` tag.

[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: OMG thank youuuu I've been looking all over the place for something like that!!!!!!!!! I totally forgot about the tilde

Comment: No problem glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery will make your life a lot easier

---

```js
$('#pre_opacity').hover(function() {
  $('#trans_box_1').addClass('transClass');
}, function() {
  $('#trans_box_1').removeClass('transClass');
});
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.trans-box-holder {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px cornflowerblue solid;
}

.trans-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#trans_box_1 {
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}


/* If you swap out #pre_opacity for body it works for some reason! */

.transClass {
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre_opacity">
        .element {
            transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 1s;
        }
    </pre>
<div class="trans-box-holder">
  <div class="trans-box" id="trans_box_1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I know I can do it that way I'm just very confused of why this doesn't work on my project. In fact the very code I do use works as long as the trigger isn't directed towards an ID or class of an element

Comment: then use the ~ selector

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is working for body is, you have css :

```
#pre_opacity:hover #trans_box_1 {
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

what it means is, it will applied if and only if you have child having id #trans_box_1 inside a div(or some other html tag) having id #pre_opacity.

When you replaced #pre_opacity with body, the above condition will passed and hover will work.

To make it work, you need to add sibling selector '**+**' or '**~**'

you css will be like this :

```
#pre_opacity:hover + .trans-box-holder #trans_box_1 {
    transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

Here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kmm2q6y4/

For more sibling selectors, check this out : https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Q: 
 "When I try to make a cube transition inside of a container when the 
 trigger div is hovered over but it isn't triggering the transition. ..."

A:
 The reason the cube isn't transitioning is because you are using a triggering element(#pre_opacity) that is not a parent of the target element(#trans_box_1 .trans-box) you want to transition.

You can add the :hover pseudo-class to the targeted element's parents( #body or .trans-box-holder) so that when either is hovered the cube will transition.

For example:

```
    .trans-box-holder:hover .trans_box {
        transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
    }
```

Edit:
Noopur Dabhi and Ylama have a better solution using the tilde and plus selector.

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
#pre_opacity:hover #trans_box_1 {
```

**To:**

```
#pre_opacity:hover + .trans-box-holder #trans_box_1 {
```

```css
pre {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.trans-box-holder {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px cornflowerblue solid;
}

.trans-box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#trans_box_1 {
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
/* If you swap out #pre_opacity for body it works for some reason! */
#pre_opacity:hover + .trans-box-holder #trans_box_1 {
    transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- The trigger -->
<pre id="pre_opacity">
    .element {
        transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 1s;
    }
</pre>
<div class="trans-box-holder">
  <div class="trans-box" id="trans_box_1"></div>
</div>
```